# Using pipelines within powershell for a loop failing with variable name Cannot validate argument on parameter

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to change the property of one of the webapp configuration using a loop. The idea is to only change ones where the property is false. I have the code below, however it is failing with the error  `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceGroupName'`

```
$is_https boolean
    Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
       Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $_.Name       
       Get-AzWebApp | ForEach-Object {
        $is_https =(Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup  -Name $appName | select HttpsOnly).HttpsOnly
        if ($webapp_https -eq $false )
          {
            Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name -HttpsOnly $true
          }
       }
   }
```

**EDIT**

I have now fixed the issue by adding a second foreach loop, however I would like there to be an If statement such that the Set-AzWebApp only runs if -httpsOnly is `$false`. At the moment it changes the setting for all web apps irrespective of whether it is required or not. The code snippet above doesnt work, however the below works as it doesnt have the if statement.

```
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
       Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $_.Name       
       Get-AzWebApp | ForEach-Object {
       Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name -HttpsOnly $true
       
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you show your ```for``` loop and how you initialise the collection you’re iterating over? It’s impossible to know what the ```$_``` automatic variable contains without seeing that…

Comment: @mclayton I have edited the problem, took on board your comments and I have a working version, the aim is to have one with the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could achieve your requirement using the below script where the `HttpsOnly` sets when it is `$false`. Below is the complete script that worked for me where I have set the values at resource group level.

```
$AllWebApps=Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>
$AllWebApps
foreach($webapp in $AllWebApps)
{
    $is_https = (Get-AzWebApp -Name $webapp.Name -ResourceGroupName $webapp.ResourceGroup).HttpsOnly
    $is_https
    if ($is_https -eq $false)
    {
        Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $webapp.ResourceGroup -Name $webapp.Name -HttpsOnly $true
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]